# python manage.py makemigrations django doesn't create all the fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations, djongo

I have one question when I am doing `python manage.py makemigrations` django doesn't create all the fields for the `Todo` Model, please help what's wrong here?

```
class Todo(models.Model):
     task = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     title = models.CharField(max_length=100),
     _date = models.CharField(max_length=100),
     categories = models.CharField(max_length=100),
     keywords = models.CharField(max_length=100),
     summary = models.TextField(),
     description = models.TextField()
```

**Migration Model**

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

initial = True

dependencies = [
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Todo',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('task', models.CharField(max_length=255)),
            ('description', models.TextField()),
        ],
    ),
]
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the trailing commas. By adding a comma at the end, you wrap the item in a singleton tuple.

Answer (score 2):

python3 manage.py makemigrations

and

python3 manage.py migrate

Comment: For me its the reverse I was using `python3 manage.py migrate`  and I was getting no output. Using just `python manage.py migrate` solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

It worked after removing `,` in Todo model.

```
class Todo(models.Model):
   task = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   _date = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   categories = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   keywords = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   summary = models.TextField()
   description = models.TextField()
```

Answer (score -1):

Create an `__init__.py` file in the `migrations/` directory.